# Can one senior project manager and one project manager exists on a project?

Tags: project-management

Our web developing Project has 2 Project managers. So our Chief engineer assigned one as Senior Project Manager another as Project Manager. So does this kind of designation Exist.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming, but about job titles.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, a whole Project Management team can be assigned to a single project.

What a Project Management team does is sharing the responsibilities and tasks that a single Project Manager would take.

In that case, it is important that the responsibilities of each member of the Project Management team are clear for everyone related to the project, including both team members and sponsors.

Regarding specifically your question about the designation of multiple Project Managers, when I need that a team member help me in the PM tasks, I usually nominate that person as Assistant Project Manager.

Calling one of them as Senior Project Manager sounds more like a job position. That designation does not clearly states which are the responsibilities of each one of the Project Managers.

Answer (score 0):

A project manager is a professional in the field of project management. Project managers can have the responsibility of the planning, execution and closing of any project.

In that case, what does the senior project manager do? he/she just review or manages the other project managers? If so, it should be a senior project manager designation on the same project.